# probability that a year has 53 mondays

Tags: probability, self-study

We have the years from 2001, 2002, 2003,... to 2010. Say, a year is chosen at random from the listed years. What is the probability that the chosen year has 53 Mondays ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't show any sort of effort, you're not very likely to get much help.

Comment: Well, I figured out the following: If it's a non-leap year, we have 52 weeks and 1 day remaining. So the probability of getting 53 Mondays in this case is 1/7. And if it's a leap year, we have 52 weeks and 2 days remaining. Hence, the probability of getting 53 Mondays in this case is 2/7.

Comment: Why not just use calendars to find out the day on which 1/1/2000 fell?  Since each year's end date determines the start date of the next, and you know when leap years are (Quick: was 2000 a leap year or not?) you can figure out exactly which of these 10 years had 53 Mondays.

Comment: Yes, that was what I had in mind at first. But then, the person who gave me the problem, asked me to solve it in a different manner.

Comment: Your figuring would be correct provided the set of years filled out one cycle of the calendar, which is $400$ years long.  This period has $400(1/4 - 1/100 + 1/400) = 97$ leap years and $303$ non-leap years. Because $400+97$ is a multiple of seven, it also contains a whole number of weeks, so the next $400$-year period begins on the same day. The proportion of $53$-Monday years in this cycle is $(1+1/4-1/100+1/400)/7=0.1775.$ However, two of them fall in the range $2001\ldots 2010$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ \Omega$ be the number of possible outcomes and $x$ be the number of desired outcomes. Then, the probability $p(x)$ of picking randomly $x$ is equal to $ p(x)= \frac{x}{\Omega} $.

In your case, you are given 10 years. This is the number of possible outcomes. Let $x$ be the number of years from 2001 to 2010 which had 53 Mondays. Then, the probability of picking randomly a year with 53 Mondays is equal to
 $ \frac{x}{10} $.